Tag Helper stop working when I upgraded project to .NET 8
I have this tag in a view:
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" value="@Model.ID" />

In the Views root folder, the file _ViewImports.cshtml exists with this content:
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

What am I missing in order for it to work?
That worked in .NET 7.
Thanks
Jaime

Hi Jaime， please try to run dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers --prerelease and dotnet restore command, then test again.

If it still not working, please try to delete the bin,obj and .vs folders, then upgrade the vs2022 the latest version.
